# apache - Can't upload >2GB file

Tags: apache-2.2, upload

Uploading files in our app works fine until we hit one that's > 2GB.

error_log shows:

```
Invalid Content-Length
(-3)Unknown error: Error reading request entity data
```

I've rebuilt the latest apache 64bit with large file support and I still get this error.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this problem too, and I'm using the latest Apache/PHP and CentOS 5.7 64-bit. PHP limits are set to above 4GB, but still cannot upload anything over 2GB?!

Comment: How about disk space? You have enough? Post output from `df -kh` assuming you're on a linux/unix box.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could also be on the client side. Some Webbrowsers do funny things with files bigger than 2GB. A good summary can be found [here](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm). Basically try first with a WebKit browser like Chrome or Safari. (These for sure are capable to send files bigger than 2GB correctly.)

Comment: Neither Chrome nor Safari use Gecko.

Comment: Sure, I meant WebKit and did correct the answer... Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your .htaccess file. You can modify that to allow larger uploads.

The .htaccess file should look something like this :

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Or you can also change this setting in your php.ini.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: …assuming of course that the original poster is running PHP. Hey, @raoul, what are you running?

Comment: ya. He said apache so I figured it would be PHP.

Comment: We don't use PHP, this is a Perl application.

Comment: Anybody think of anything else?